# Error when running the reference solution for Construct Binary Tree from Preorder and Inorder Traversal in Leetcode?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking at LeetCode problem: [105. Construct Binary Tree from Preorder and Inorder Traversal](https://leetcode.com/problems/construct-binary-tree-from-preorder-and-inorder-traversal/description/):

> Given two integer arrays `preorder` and `inorder` where `preorder` is the preorder traversal of a binary tree and `inorder` is the inorder traversal of the same tree, construct and return *the binary tree*.
>
> Template code:
>
> ```
> # Definition for a binary tree node.
> # class TreeNode:
> #     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
> #         self.val = val
> #         self.left = left
> #         self.right = right
> class Solution:
>     def buildTree(self, preorder: List[int], inorder: List[int]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
> ```

I used the code that is provided in the [Editorial of the challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/construct-binary-tree-from-preorder-and-inorder-traversal/editorial/):

> ```
> class Solution:
>     def buildTree(self, preorder: List[int], inorder: List[int]) -> TreeNode:
>
>         def array_to_tree(left, right):
>             nonlocal preorder_index
>             # if there are no elements to construct the tree
>             if left > right: return None
>
>             # select the preorder_index element as the root and increment it
>             root_value = preorder[preorder_index]
>             root = TreeNode(root_value)
>
>
>             preorder_index += 1
>
>             # build left and right subtree
>             # excluding inorder_index_map[root_value] element because it's the root
>             root.left = array_to_tree(left, inorder_index_map[root_value] - 1)
>             root.right = array_to_tree(inorder_index_map[root_value] + 1, right)
>
>             return root
>
>         preorder_index = 0
>
>         # build a hashmap to store value -> its index relations
>         inorder_index_map = {}
>         for index, value in enumerate(inorder):
>             inorder_index_map[value] = index
>
>         return array_to_tree(0, len(preorder) - 1)
> ```

#### Problem

My question is about running this test case:

```
preorder = [4,1,3,6,8]
inorder = [6,1,8,4,3]
tree = Solution().buildTree(preorder, inorder)
```

When running it, an exception occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 43, in <module>
    tree = Solution().buildTree(preorder,inorder)
  File "main.py", line 30, in buildTree
    return array_to_tree(0, len(preorder) - 1)
  File "main.py", line 22, in array_to_tree
    root.left = array_to_tree(left, inorder_index_map[root_value] - 1)
  File "main.py", line 22, in array_to_tree
    root.left = array_to_tree(left, inorder_index_map[root_value] - 1)
  File "main.py", line 22, in array_to_tree
    root.left = array_to_tree(left, inorder_index_map[root_value] - 1)
  File "main.py", line 23, in array_to_tree
    root.right = array_to_tree(inorder_index_map[root_value] + 1, right)
  File "main.py", line 22, in array_to_tree
    root.left = array_to_tree(left, inorder_index_map[root_value] - 1)
  File "main.py", line 19, in array_to_tree
    root_value = preorder[preorder_index]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

#### Analysis

The following is my manual calculation:

The tree should look like this:

```
    4
   / \
  1   3
 / \
6   8
```

Hand Calculating:

```
preorder = [4, 1, 3, 6, 8]
hashmap: {6:0 ; 1:1 ; 8:2 ; 4:3 ; 3:4 }
preorderindex = 0
```

loop 1:

```
  left = 0 right = 3
  preorderindex = 0 => root value = 4 => new right = 2
  tree: 

    4
```

loop 2:

```
  left = 0 right = 2
  preorderindex = 1 => root value = 1 => new right = 0
  tree: 

      4
     /
    1
```

loop 3:

```
  left =0 right = 0
  preorderindex = 2 => root value = 3 => new right = 3
  tree:

       4
      /
     1
    /
   3
```

At this step, there is already an error, and I really wonder where is the mistake?

I'm so confused, I don't believe there is a mistake in this code, but then I can't figure out where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preorder and inorder sequences that you have there are not compatible. There is no tree that has [4, 1, 3, 6, 8] as preorder and [6,1,8,4,3] as inorder sequences.

We can prove that as follows:

An inorder traversal will visit the "leftmost" node first, which in this case is node 6. The preorder sequence will only visit the leftmost node after having visited the nodes on the path from the root to that node, so that means the tree must have this branch:

```
         4
        /
       1
      /
     3
    /
   6
```

But that is a contradiction, that means in the inorder traversal, 6 and 3 should be visited before 1, but that is not the case.

Assuming you started out with a given tree:

```
    4
   / \
  1   3
 / \
6   8
```

...then indeed the inorder sequence is [6,1,8,4,3]. But the preorder sequence is not [4,1,3,6,8], but [4,1,6,8,3].

The sequence [4,1,3,6,8] is something different: it is a level-order (breadth-first) sequence.

As you provide inconsistent data to the solution code, it runs into an error.